# Make the application wait until http response is received

Tags: android, multithreading

I have function that runs to authenticate user access every time user starts the app. On every start userid & token are sent to server for authentication and when they are authenticated then user can use the app.

Issue the I cant make HTTP calls over main thread. And over separate thread I cant stop to wait for the response.

So how can I make the application wait until the authentication response is received?

```
if (usrObj.authenticateUser()) {
                        Intent controllerActivity = new Intent("android.intent.action.Main");
                        startActivity(controllerActivity);
                    } else {
                       …
                    }
//User.java
public boolean authenticateUser() {
        Thread thr_authenticateUser = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //Make HTTP authentication request and wait for the reply.
            }
        });
        thr_authenticateUser.start();
        return authenticationStatus;
    }
```

Comment: `AsyncTask` with `ProgressDialog` will create the Magic..!

Comment: using a ProgressBar is the recommended approach to indicate progress and then hiding it when the request is completed. Also this might a little over the top, but consider using Robospice or a specialized library to do network requests to save you some troubles later on https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to hold the UI thread. The user will think that the app is crashed and they may get an app is not responding.

You can have Splash activity to check your authentication with an `AsyncTask` for example and an indeterminate `ProgressBar` and if it's successful then navigate to the App else go to Login or Sign up.

Or you can make you layout not visible by using `android:visibility="gone"` and make a ProgressBar visible until the authentication happens then switch you main view to visible again by using `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` on you View object and the ProgressDialog to invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If a standard listadapter is your main activity/fragment , you could do the following:

before auth on the token , just setup the adapter ( emptydatalist ) and show the list on the UI with the empty message ( "checking user auth" ). If you on wifi , it may all be so fast that they wont see any initial UI.

If you already have a token that may be valid and can use it on dataCall to get the list for the adapter, then make a data call you may get list or may get error ( no auth )

If you get data, then update the adapter's Data-list and call "notify()" on the adapter and you are done....

If you dont get data or if you dont want to make that initial call for data using the stale token then....

make the call to validate use...

make the data call using the response from the above.. ( valid token )

refresh data in adapter

call notify on the adapter.

Note all data calls occur on background thread. With callbacks to UI for Notify that occurs on main ui thread.

Note you dont need your own threads to follow this kinda pattern because the framework has built-in api stuff for this use case.  As mention, you can use asyncTask or you can use  a message looper with queues for http runnables and their event-driven callbacks  (on http-response,  Handlers to read the response data and to message back to the main UI )